# Aggregate top 3 values of a numerical column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a column of species abundance

```
  Pct_Cov Species Site Plot
1    2.25    AMLA AC      1
2    4.75   BECA4 AC      1
3    9.50    BEPA AC      1
4    7.00    BEPO AC      1
5    9.25    PIRU AC      1
6    2.25    PIRI AC      1
```

tail

```
tail(st.ov)
       Pct_Cov Species Site Plot
612207     8.0    QUGA ZI  527
612208     1.0   RHAR4 ZI   527
612209     0.5   ARTR2 ZI   527
612210     1.0    POFE ZI   527
612211     3.0   VICIA ZI   527
612212     0.5    ARLU ZI  527
```

There are a LOT of plots here, 12438 to be exact. Each plot has a variety of different species, etc. I'm trying to write a function that creates a new column to calculate the ratio of the abundance of the dominant species / abundance of the subordinate species.

"Dominant" would be the sum of the top 1/4 of the species per each plot. So if a plot had 20 species, it would be the sum of the abundance of the 4 most abundant species.

I'm having a hard time going about this and was wondering if anyone had any tips. It would also be helpful to know what those species are, but that seems to be tricky.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another tidyverse option. Since your data only has 6 rows for each of two `Plot`s, I'll go with the "top 2" and "all but top 2", instead of your "4". It's easily modified.

```r
dat %>%
  group_by(Plot) %>%
  mutate(R = dense_rank(Pct_Cov)) %>%
  summarize(Ratio = sum(Pct_Cov[R %in% 1:2]) / sum(Pct_Cov[! R %in% 1:2]))
# # A tibble: 2 x 2
#    Plot Ratio
#   <int> <dbl>
# 1     1 0.359
# 2   527 0.273
```

This does not protect against plots with few unique species. For that, one might add some row-counting logic:

```r
dat %>%
  group_by(Plot) %>%
  mutate(R = dense_rank(Pct_Cov)) %>%
  summarize(Ratio = if (n() > (2+2)) sum(Pct_Cov[R %in% 1:2]) / sum(Pct_Cov[! R %in% 1:2]) else NA_real_)
```

If you get an `NA`, that means that that `Plot` had too few unique species.

Also, it doesn't acknowledge the possibility of 3 (my "2" plus one) having the same `Pct_Cov`, which sounds unlikely but would be a corner-case that will skew the math.

---

Data

```r
dat <- structure(list(Pct_Cov = c(2.25, 4.75, 9.5, 7, 9.25, 2.25, 8, 1, 0.5, 1, 3, 0.5), Species = c("AMLA", "BECA4", "BEPA", "BEPO", "PIRU", "PIRI", "QUGA", "RHAR4", "ARTR2", "POFE", "VICIA", "ARLU"), Site = c("AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "ZI", "ZI", "ZI", "ZI", "ZI", "ZI"), Plot = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 527L, 527L, 527L, 527L, 527L, 527L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "612207", "612208", "612209", "612210", "612211", "612212"))
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `count` to get the frequency count of 'plot', 'Species', `arrange` by 'plot' and `desc`ending order of 'n', then grouped by 'plot', create the ratio by taking the `sum` of first 3 'n' values divided by the `sum` of the rest and join with the original data

```
library(dplyr)
out <- df1 %>%
   count(plot, Species) %>%
   arrange(plot, desc(n)) %>%
   group_by(plot) %>%
   mutate(ratio = sum(n[1:3])/sum(n[-(1:3)])) %>%
   right_join(df1)
```